# Read in a 10 character string and print out each character on new line

Tags: python

```
def readinstring():   
            try:
                word = str(input('Enter string'))
                #raise Exception
            except ValueError:
                print('bhai string print karna hay')
            #except Exception:
                #print('more than 10 characters, thats wrong nibba')
            else:
                for letter in word:
                    print (letter)
            return



readinstring()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this code says, for every character in the string print the character.

```
string = input('enter string')

for character in string:
    print(character)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow @Sam Taaghol!  This doesn't address the OP's requirement that the string is limited to 10 characters.  If you update your answer, please note that it's encouraged to provide an explanation as to how your answer works. Thanks!